# whereHas vs join -> applying global scopes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a query with a few joins and global scopes for each model, for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM products p
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT *
  FROM orders o
  WHERE o.user_id = 4
  AND o.status_id = 1
  AND o.user_id = 3
  AND EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM suborders s
    WHERE s.status_id = 2
  )
);
```

This means that I can simply write a few `whereHas` statements and my query will have some nested `EXIST` clauses, but all global scopes (like the `user_id` on the `orders` table) will be applied automatically:

```
$this->builder->whereHas('orders', function ($q) {
  $q->where('status_id', '=', 1)
    ->whereHas('suborder', function ($q) {
      $q->where('status_id', '=', 2);
    });
});
```

The problem is that it's slow, it would be much better to have something with plain `JOIN`s instead of ugly nested `EXIST` clauses:

```
SELECT *
FROM products p
INNER JOIN orders o ON p.order_id = o.id
INNER JOIN suborders s ON o.id = s.order_id
WHERE o.status_id = 1
AND u.user_id = 3
AND s.status_id = 2;
```

The problem with this is that I need to use query builder to join these:

```
$this->builder->join('orders', 'products.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
              ->join('suborders', 'orders.id', '=', 'suborders.order_id')
              ->where('orders.status_id', 1)
              ->where('suborders.id', 2);
```

And that will not include any of my global scopes on `Order` and `Suborder` model. I need to do it manually:

```
$this->builder->join('orders', 'products.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
              ->join('suborders', 'orders.id', '=', 'suborders.order_id')
              ->where('orders.status_id', 1)
              ->where('suborders.id', 2)
              ->where('orders.user_id', 3);
```

It's bad, because I need to replicate my global scopes logic every time I write a query like this, while `whereHas` applies them automatically.

Is there a way to join a table, and have all global scopes from the joined model applied automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with a similar issue before and come up with some approach.

First, lets define a macro for Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder in a service provider:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause;

class AppServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Builder::macro('hasJoinedWith', function ($table) {
            return collect(
                $this->getQuery()->joins
            )
            ->contains(function (JoinClause $joinClause) use ($table) {
                return $joinClause->table === $table;
            })
        });
    }
}
```

Then, lets define the scopes:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function scopeOrderStatus($query, $orderStatusId)
    {
        if (! $query->hasJoinedWith('orders')) {
            $query->join('orders', 'products.order_id', '=', 'orders.id');
        }

        return $query->where('orders.status_id', $orderStatusId)
    }

    public function scopeOrderUser($query, $userId)
    {
        if (! $query->hasJoinedWith('orders')) {
            $query->join('orders', 'products.order_id', '=', 'orders.id');
        }

        return $query->where('orders.user_id', $userId)
    }

    public function scopeSubOrder($query, $subOrderId)
    {
        if (! $query->hasJoinedWith('orders')) {
            $query->join('orders', 'products.order_id', '=', 'orders.id');
        }

        if (! $query->hasJoinedWith('suborders')) {
            $query->join('suborders', 'orders.id', '=', 'suborders.order_id');
        }

        return $query->where('suborders.id', $subOrderId)
    }
}
```

Finally, you use the scopes together:

```
Product::orderStatus(1)
    ->subOrder(2)
    ->orderUser(3)
    // This is optional. There are possibly duplicate products.
    ->distinct()
    ->get();
```

This is the best approach that I can come up with, there may be better ones.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that what you describe can't be true (will provide proof below). `EXISTS` don't make query slower and in 99% of case it make faster!
So laravel don't provide ability to make joins for relations from box.

I saw different solutions for this and package on github, but I will not provide link to it, because when I reviewed logic, found a lot of problems with field selecting and rare cases.

1. Laravel don't generate code with `EXISTS` as you describe, it add relation search by ID to each `EXISTS` subquery like

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT *
  FROM orders
  WHERE o.user_id = 4
  AND o.status_id = 1
  AND o.id = p.order_id
  AND EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM suborders s
    WHERE s.status_id = 2
    AND s.id = o.suborder_id
  )
);
```

attention to `AND o.id = p.order_id` and `AND s.id = o.suborder_id`

2. When you do select with joins, you should exactly set `SELECT` from main table, to have right filled Model fields.
3. Global scopes are global. Purpose to be really global. If you have more then 1-2 places without them, then you should find another solution instead of global scopes. Otherwise you application will be very hard to support and write new code. Developer should not remember every time, that there can be global scopes that he should turn off